# R str_match regex between ( and =

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

Im using str_match in dyplr in R to extract a string from a column and put it into a new column.

The full strings look like:

```
 Chemical: (BETA-CYFLUTHRIN = 118831)
```

I just want 'BETA-CYFLUTHRIN' so I'm trying to use regex to get the value between ( and = but I've been getting

```
(BETA-CYFLUTHRIN =
```

I know this is probably a really silly question but I've been struggling with this for a while and still can't see to get it. This is what I have so far: any suggestions? thanks!

```
ru2 <- ru2%>%mutate(chem2 = str_extract(chem, "[(](.*?) ="))
```

Comment: `sub(".*\\((.*)\\s=.*","\\1","Chemical: (BETA-CYFLUTHRIN = 118831)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may still use `str_extract`, but you need to use *zero-width assertions* to only grab a piece of a pattern inside some context:

```
str_extract(chem, "(?<=\\().*?(?= =)")
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\\()` - there must be a `(` char immediately to the left of the current location
- `.*?` - matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?= =)` - there must be a space and `=` immediately to the right of the current location.

**[See the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e4Ikay/1)**

A base R equivalent could look like

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=\\().*?(?= =)", x, perl=TRUE))
# => [1] "BETA-CYFLUTHRIN"
```

See an [R demo online](https://ideone.com/pagVgr).

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_match` instead, and grab the second value. You don't have to change your pattern at all:

```
x <- "Chemical: (BETA-CYFLUTHRIN = 118831)"
str_match(x, "[(](.*?) =")
     [,1]                 [,2]             
# [1,] "(BETA-CYFLUTHRIN =" "BETA-CYFLUTHRIN"
str_match(x, "[(](.*?) =")[1,2]
# [1] "BETA-CYFLUTHRIN"
```

This works because `str_match` was designed to extract capturing groups (things inside `()`), which is a very useful addition to the regex functions in R indeed.